# Does Optaplanner version 6.3 has Evolutionary algorithms or hyper heuristics implemented?

Tags: optaplanner

I just want to know if Optaplanner version 6.3 has the Evolutionary algorithms and hyper heuristics implemented or not?

I want to use the simulated annealing algorithm to solve my problem and to compare the results if I use the genetic algorithms.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 6.3 has no Evolutionary algorithms yet and no build-in support for Hyper Heuristics yet. Both are planned for future versions.

Research compo's such as International Time Tabling Competition, Roadef Challenge etc show that Local Search consistently beat Genetic Algorithms, so I wouldn't worry about Evolutionary Algorithms too much.

Hyper Heuristics on the other hand, are undeniably important. Some of them can be build on top of OptaPlanner, by using programmatic configuration etc. But Hyper Heuristics currently are still a form of bleeding edge rocket science, so it can be hard to do so.